# How to abstract common build logic from unrelated Gradle builds?

Tags: gradle

I am currently migrating several Maven projects to Gradle. Some of them are simple, some are multi-module builds, but all are stored in separate Git repositories. All projects rely on a common "Master POM" which defines the following sections:

- `organization`
- `properties`
- `reporting`
- `distributionManagement`
- `build` / `plugins`
- `repositories`

For example, all projects use the same Maven repository (Nexus).

How can I introduce this kind of common configuration to Gradle, ideally stored in a separate Git repository?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can check out this [sample](https://docs.gradle.org/current/samples/sample_publishing_convention_plugins.html).
Generally sharing build logic in Gradle is achieved through plugins mechanism.

This [documentation](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/implementing_gradle_plugins.html#header) describes how to create plugins, which can then be published to maven repository and applied in different projects.

For sharing dependency versions there is [version catalogs](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/platforms.html#sec:sharing-catalogs) or [platforms](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_platform_plugin.html#sec:java_platform_publishing)